# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get days difference between 2 days and I am getting below error.
Could any one please help

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL,((dbo.convertToUnixTime(GETDATE())-p.CREATEDDATE)))
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 79
>
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those functions are product specific.)

Comment: Hi @jarlh I am using sql server

Comment: CREATEDDATE data type?

Comment: @jarlh its datetime

Comment: What if the definition of `dbo.convertToUnixTime`? Why are you defining your value as just `decimal`, where the precision and scale? Why do you appear to be subtracting a date away from another? Dates aren't numbers, it doesn't make sense to "subtract" `2020-09-17T19:12:59.462` from `2020-09-25T10:47:04.123`.

Comment: Hi larnu,   I need to see the days difference for 2 days as I need calculate some time period.I took decimal as I need to see my days in decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fractional days, then you can take the difference in another unit, say seconds, and divide:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, p.CREATEDATE, GETDATE()) / (24.0 * 60 * 60)
```

Note that for `DATEDIFF()` the older date goes first.  I assume `p.CREATEDATE` is in the past and you want a positive number.

If you are dealing with dates far in the past or the future, you might want to use `minute` rather than `second` or alternatively `DATEDIFF_BIG()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date functions:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),p.CREATEDATE)
```

Comment: Hi @wouter .I did this but I need to see my days in decimals too.But I am not getting that.

Comment: Then do a DATEDIFF in hours and divide by 24 , or difference in minutes, seconds, etc. depending on how precise you want it.

Comment: Btw if you want to use your convertToUnixTime function, then you should convert both datetimes (the getdate() and the CREATEDATE).  But that will be much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`datediff()` always return an integer value, expressed in the unit your are giving as first argument.

If you want something accurate, you can compute the date difference in seconds, then use artithmetics to convert to a number of days:

```
datediff(second, p.createdate, getdate()) / 60.0 / 60 / 24
```